# how to smoothly add include directories for various 3rd party libraries under common root?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to learn cmake and I can't find a smart way to resolve common problem.

I would like to use a couple of 3rd party libraries. Let's say I keep them all under the same root (the more advanced case: there is a couple of such roots). Let's say that they have structure as follows:

```
root
--Lib1                 // headers here 
--Lib2
  --include            // headers here
--Lib3                 // headers here
  --private_headers    // ...and here (non public)
```

I would like to achieve a goal that I'm able to specify in cmakelists.txt which libraries I would like to use but:

- without specifying where is the root - it have to be independent of my libs directory structure (probably it should come from some standard cmake env variable but it seems that none of the CMAKE_xxx_PATH suits)
- without bothering with private header dependencies and subfolders in Lib3 (I just want to include top level header(s) and all lower level headers included from it with their relative path(s) must be found)

How to achieve these goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use by anyone with any libs directory structure

that wont work out-of-the-box. in the end, you need the path to all your 3rd party libraries, no matter if they reside in a common root or in separate directories. in any case, minimally an `XX_INCLUDE_PATH` and `XX_LIBRARIES` is needed to point to each of those packages' respective locations.

the answer to your problem is to use FindXXX.cmake modules for each library.
they are designed to contain the logic to find the libraries/include dirs for any 3rd party package. cmake comes [with a pile of them](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-modules.7.html), and there are [more written every day](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Module_Maintainers). they all use "default" logic and paths and will need aid if the packages requested reside at a nonstandard location; see the [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html).
if you cant find the ones for your 3rd party libraries, code up your own one: [find_package interface guidelines for MODULE mode](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules). make sure you set the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` correctly to include your folder first when "overwriting" an existing FindLIBX.cmake to tailor it to your needs.

ultimately, you will then invoke something like this in your main `CMakeLists.txt`, provided you have a `FindLIBX.cmake` on your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`:

```
SET(USE_LIBX TRUE)

if(USE_LIBX)
   find_package(LIBX QUIET)
endif()
...
add_library(my_main_lib ${sources})
...
if(LIBX_FOUND)
   target_link_libraries(my_main_lib PUBLIC ${LIBX_LIBRARIES})
   target_include_directories(my_main_lib PUBLIC ${LIBX_INCLUDE_PATH})
endif()
```

here the flag "USE_LIBX" enables you to easily switch the use of components on/off.
you can also use the commands [uncletall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184668/2048756) described above, however, the `target_` commands are more specific and dont add the libraries to ALL your projects targets; depends on the complexity of your project.

and: the fact that "public" headers will automatically include "private" headers correctly will depend on how well your 3rd party library is written. private headers, however, should never be necessary to build against your 3rd party library, that's why they're private. something different are "dependent" headers that will be included by your "public" headers. these are then necessarily also "public" as they need to be moved (correctly relative) to wherever your "public" headers reside for inclusion.

Comment: Great explanation. You are right - my vision was a bit odd. Now it seems I can see the light. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. 
In this solution you have an environment variable LIB_ROOT_DIR that points to you root directory. The `include_directories` and `link_directories` are then used to add the directories to you project.

```
include_directories( 
${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/Lib1
${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/Lib2/include
${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/Lib3
)
link_directories(${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/Lib1 ${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/Lib2 ${LIB_ROOT_DIR}/Lib3)
```

Comment: Yes, it is proper but have one shortcoming: it depends on my specific variable; I would like to depend on standard variables only making it simple to use by anyone with any libs directory structure;